łatwy—syllable structure?
With Polish, I always struggle to divide pronunciation into syllables.
Note that, in this thread, I'm exclusively concerned with phonetic syllables, not orthographic.
What, precisely, is syllable structure of 'łatwy'?
Is it [ˈwɐ.tfɪ] or [ˈwɐt.fɪ] ?
I tend to the former, because it seems that in spoken Polish consecutive consonants seem to cluster syllable-internally.

When consonant-ending native prefix is attached to consonant-beginning morpheme or consonant-beginning native suffix is attached to consonant-ending morpheme, then it is preferred to make syllable boundary at boundary of this prefix or suffix (e.g. ⟨rozwijać⟩, which has prefix ⟨roz-⟩, is [rɔzˈvi.jät͡ɕ], not [rɔˈzvi.jät͡ɕ], while ⟨pozwijać⟩, which has prefix ⟨po-⟩, is [pɔˈzvi.jät͡ɕ], not [pɔzˈvi.jät͡ɕ]).
In other cases, Polish language tries to respect Sonority Sequencing Principle (SSP) and Maximal Onset Principle (MOP), as also mentioned here.
⟨łatwy⟩: [ˈwä.tfɘ̟]

SSP and MOP, is it about internal structure of individual syllables or 'syllable structure' as used in my question ? In my question, 'syllable structure' essentially means 'the naturally ordered list of all the syllables of the subject word'.

Put another way, I'd like to know the result of correct phonetic syllabification of łatwy ('easy'), 'correct' according to Polish language. SSP seems to deal with the internal structure of syllables, things like nucleus, onset, rhyme, coda, medial, maybe tone.

@philo I wrote what is syllabification of that word in my answer. In this case it is due to Maximal Onset Principle. I also note that Sonority Sequencing Principle is only a guide for syllabification in Polish, but is not an absolute rule which would disallow existence of some words at all in Polish. There are words violating this rule in Polish.

I agree, you answered my question, and that correctly apparently. The answer is [ˈwä.tfɘ̟]. You sure about 'advanced ɘ' ? Why not 'raised ɘ', thus ɪ essentially ? And what is a 'native' suffix or prefix ? I agree, MOP may explain syllable structure of 'easy'. I prefer the name 'Maximum Initial Principle' over MOP. 'Chinese' syllable model is just more intricate than classical syllable model.

@philo That vowel seems to be always slightly advanced, and sometimes slightly raised, from cardinal [ɘ]. See also this. [ɪ] is used for a certain vowel in English and it sounds slightly different from a vowel in Polish.

@philo Native affixes are those inherited from Proto-Slavic language, and most of them should exist in all Slavic languages, so they should be still recognized if a word was borrowed from another Slavic language to Polish language. By non-native affixes, I mean especially affixes in words wholy borrowed from Latin, French, German etc. (e.g. Latin ab-, ad-, ex-). For non-native affixes, boundaries of syllables may or may not match boundaries used with native affixes. See also this.

@philo Prefixes like de-, re-, super- have become partially productive with native words, so syllabification of words with these prefixes is more likely to match syllabification of fully native words.
